# Saving Nanosecond Timestamps in MongoDB (Generated by Go, Saved using Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, go, apache-kafka, unix-timestamp

I am trying to store Unix timestamps in nanoseconds into the `Date` type field of a Mongodb database.

The unix timestamps in nanoseconds are generated in a Go program (with `time.Now().UnixNano()`), submitted to Kafa to be read by a Node.js script which uses `mongoose` to write the payload object containing the unix timestamp in nanoseconds to the Mongodb store.

However this is throwing an error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: trade validation failed: timestamp: Cast to Date failed for value "1544720051987010000" at path "timestamp"

Is there a better way to store unix timestamps in nanosecond in Mongodb?

Comment: Instead of `Date` store it as an integer? [Date objects use a Unix Time Stamp, an integer value that is the number of **milliseconds** since 1 January 1970 UTC.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Curious why you wouldn't use Kafka Connect framework to read from Kafka and write to Mongo...

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm using Mongodb transactions, so I went with a Kafa consumer instead of a Kafka connector. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mongo enough, but I personally prefer writing little code as possible to avoid reinventing the wheel. If the Mongo Java API supports transactions, then I see no reason why Kafka Connect couldn't use them. However, transaction support should be enabled at the Kafka level as well if you really want "exactly once" delivery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to store Unix timestamps in nanoseconds into the Date type
>   field of a Mongodb database. Nyxynyx

That is not going to work.

---

> Internally, Date objects are stored as a signed 64-bit integer
>   representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1,
>   1970).

[MongoDB Reference: Date()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timestamp := time.Now().UnixNano() / int64(time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println(timestamp)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/21S_DeVA4jv

Output:

```
1257894000000
```

---

To store Unix nanoseconds, use the long data type.